# Button is out of container in Bootstrap

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 to design my website. In a large window my button appears fine within its gray box and border.  However, when I resize the window to check responsiveness, the button ends up being outside the boundaries of the container.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 gray-box top-space">
  <h3><?php echo __("Test");?></h3>
  <p><?php echo __("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in est nec mauris dapibus porta sit amet sit amet diam. Cras sit amet imperdiet elit. Nunc vehicula consectetur augue a pretium.");?></p>
  <a href="/pricing/" class="btn-primary pull-right" ><?php echo __("Test");?></a>
</div>
```

And here's the css for the `gray-box`.

```
.gray-box {
  background-color: #F5F4F4;
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong or what needs to be done? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. how do you expect us to reproduce the problem with the provided code..? please provide sufficient info to reproduce the problem. or reproduce it as a small demo in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something similar...

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to add the `btn` class to your button.  Buttons always require the btn class in addition to the btn-default (or -primary, etc.).  The btn class styles the element to look like the button and the btn-* classes apply the appropriate color and hover styles.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions off the top of my head.

1) Throw a `.clearfix` in after your `pull-right` to reset it:

```
<div class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Button</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

2) Put the button in its own div:

```
<div >
  <a href="" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Button</a>
</div>
```

Also, no need to classify `col-xs-12` and `col-sm-12` and `col-md-4` — the default is `col-xs-12` until it hits something else, so you can just do `col-md-4` for the same result.